# Show that the sequence $\frac{1}{n}x_n$ is Cauchy, where $x_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis

I would be interested in why exactly I can't just distribute $\frac{1}{n}$ to each term, take the limit and have them all go to zero. All attempts at using the definition have proved fruitless. In an attempt to use monotone convergence, I can show it's bounded fairly easily, but showing that is decreasing is difficult.  Thank you in advance, sorry for poor formatting.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\leq\frac{1}{n}\left(1+\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{t}dt\right)=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\log n}{n}\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding correctly, the inequality is true because the integral is a sum which contains every term of the LHS, plus some others? Why do you need +1? is it strictly to deal with n=1?

Comment: That's tricky, if you draw the graph of $1/t$, you will find that the first rectangle that is below the graph ends with endpoint $1/2$, if you start with $1$, then the rectangle is above the graph.

Comment: And one thing, you cannot start the rectangle with starting point $0$ and end with $1$, then the integral has to be $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{n}1/tdt$, then the integral diverges, nothing to help here.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument does not work since the number of terms increases as $n$ increases. So the fact that each term goes to zero does not mean the sum goes to zero. For instance it fails on $$\frac{1}{n}(1+1 + \ldots +1) $$ where there are $n$ ones.

Instead, we can use the fact that $$1 +\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n} = \log(n) + O(1)$$ so your sequence is $$ \frac{\log(n)}{n} + O(1/n)\to 0.$$

I'm not sure why the problem asks to show the Cauchy property rather than just convergence which is equivalent... I can't see an elegant way to show the Cauchy property directly (which of course does not mean there isn't one.)